# Send the body message with the css code using PHPMailer does not work

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm using PHPMailer for sending mail, I have code as below:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="myform">
        <label for="name">Objet:</label>
        <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="input validate[required] TextInput" />

        <label for="email">Destinataire:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="input validate[required,custom[email]] text-input" />



        <label for="about">Message:</label>
        <textarea name="about" id="about" rows="4" cols="40" class="validate[required] text-input">
            <?php
                while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                    echo $data['valeur'];
                }
            ?>
        </textarea>

        <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Envoyer"  class="btnValider"/></p>
    </form>
<?php


    // copy file pdf from  http://archi-graphi.com/arcancianev/pdf.php to new file sejour.pdf
    $ourFileName = "Collaborateur.pdf";
    $ourFileHandle = fopen($ourFileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");        
    $htmlFile = file_get_contents('http://www.archi-graphi.com/activite/v1/pdfCola.php?projet_id='.$_REQUEST['id']);
    //$pdfHtml = ('sejour.pdf');
    file_put_contents($ourFileName,$htmlFile);
    fclose($ourFileHandle);
    // end copy
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    require_once('class.phpmailer.php');        
    $mail  = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()" 

    $body = $_POST['about'];
    $mail->CharSet="windows-1251";
    $mail->CharSet="utf-8";     
    $mail->AddReplyTo("maly.nu_cute@ymail.com","Maly");     
    $mail->SetFrom('maly.nu_cute@ymail.com', 'Maly');       
    $mail->AddReplyTo("maly.nu_cute@ymail.com","Maly");

    $address = $_POST['email'];
    $mail->AddAddress($address, $address);      
    $mail->Subject  = $_POST['subject'];

    $mail->AltBody  = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test     
    $mail->MsgHTML($body);      
    $mail->AddAttachment("Collaborateur.pdf");      // attachment       
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
      echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
      echo "Message envoy&eacute;!";
    }
}

?>
```

In the message, I use textarea that its value I take it from database that contain the CSS code with it.when I send mail it works but the style css it not work like font color it not displays, I do not know how to fix this?Anyone help me please, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the PHP `mail()` function is `text/plain`. In your `mail()` headers, change the content-type to `text/html` and try. To do that add the below code.

```
$mail->IsHTML(true);
```

***Also*** You should'nt work with external CSS files in emails. Try inline CSS

```
<p style="color:sienna;margin-left:20px">This is a paragraph.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it still not work, my code that is the code from databse like `<p>
 Bonjour,</p>
<p>
 <strong>test</strong> mail <span style="color:#ff0000;"><em>collaborateur</em></span></p>`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add that your email is html. Try adding below before calling send:

```
$mail->IsHTML(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$mail->IsHTML(true);
```

try this